# ansi-color of telnet mode go wrong in emacs

Tags: emacs, telnet

I am using latest `emacs24.2`.

I have add (add-hook ‘`telnet-mode-hook ‘ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on`) to my `.emacs`.
   But `emacs` refuse to render my latest command output colorful;

**It means:**

```
  # ls 

    [01;34mMC[0m/
```

then after next `ls` the old one will be `MC` in blue, but current `ls` output was still scrambled.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The strange behavior was cause by expect.el. In expect.el called: `(set-process-filter process nil)`, which cause comint cannot filter process output. `(set-process-filter process 'comint-output-filter-functions)` fixed problem.

Answer (score 0):

This bugged me for a while, until I edited the telnet-filter function in my  telnet.el file by adding the following line:

```
(and telnet-replace-c-g
    (subst-char-in-region last-insertion (point) ?\C-g
        telnet-replace-c-g t))

;; Following line inserted for ansi-color.
(ansi-color-apply-on-region last-insertion (point)) 

;; If point is after the insertion place, move it
;; along with the text.
(if (> delta 0)
    (goto-char (+ (process-mark proc) delta))))))
```